# Characterisation of $\mathbf{Hom}(C,F)$

Tags: category-theory, grothendieck-topologies

$\def\C{\underline C}\def\hom{\mathbf{Hom}}\def\ker{\mathbf{Ker}}$
Let $\C$ be a category, let $C$ be a sieve on $\C$ with a basis $\{S_i\}$ and let $F:C^{op}\to\mathbf{Set}$ be a functor.

Then [*Topologies et Faisceaux* by **Demazure**](https://webusers.imj-prg.fr/~patrick.polo/SGA3/Exp4-23mai11.pdf) (Proposition 4.1.4, p.198) states that

> There is a functorial isomorphism in F:
>   $$
> \hom(C,F)\cong\ker\left(\prod_i\hom(S_i,F)\rightrightarrows\prod_{i,j}\hom(S_i\times S_j,F)\right).
> $$

But I cannot find this isomorphism.

I think for any $f\in\hom(C,F)$, we can send it to $\prod_i(f_i)$ where $f_i$ sends elements of a non-empty $\hom(X,S_i)$ to the unique element in the image of $f_X:C(X)\rightarrow F(X)$, and this belongs to the kernel.

I am confused why this is an isomorphism. I know not how to send an element in the kernel to $\hom(C,F)$.

Any hint or reference is sincerely welcomed.

Comment: The isomorphism is almost surely given by the maps $\hom(C,F) \to \hom(S_i, F)$ induced by maps $S_i \to C$.

Comment: I think this is the same as the map I described in the question, but how can one show it is an isomorphism?